# Проверить правильность решения?

Tags: php

```
$n = 3;

for ($i=0; $i < 10 ; $i++) { 
    if ((($i % $n) == 0) AND ($i != 0)) {
        echo $i.'<br/>';
    }
}
```

Определить кратно ли заданное число 3.
Если нет вывести остаток.
Не уверен в правильности решения , буду благодарен за любую помощь...

Comment: И где же у Вас в код попадает "заданное число"?

Comment: Предполагаю использование rand()

Comment: остаток-то где?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If ($rem = (($num=rand(1, 100)) % 3) == 0) {
    echo "Число ".$num." делится на 3.";
} else {
    echo "Число ".$num." не делится на 3, остаток ".$rem;
}
```

Генерирует случайное число в диапазоне от 1 до 100, затем проверяет, делится ли оно на 3, и выводит результат проверки.

То же в формате функции:

```
function check($num, $div) {
    If ($rem = $num % $div) == 0) {
        return "Число ".$num." делится на ".$div.".";
    } else {
        return "Число ".$num." не делится на ".$div.", остаток ".$rem;
    }
}

echo check(rand(1, 100), 3);
```

Comment: никогда не понимал, зачем конкатенировать то, что можно вписать внутрь? :) имхо читабельность строк с конкатенацией страдает

Comment: @teran да я PHP вообще не владею...

Comment: @teran А для меня наоборот. А еще больше читабельность, на мой взгляд, у `printf()`

Comment: Вот так получился ответ , теперь стало все понятней куда более-чем ))))
Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Не правильно. Ваш код для всех чисел от 0 до 9 проверяет делится ли оно на `$n` и не равно ли нулю? Если условия выполняются, то выводит это число

Вот такой код делает то, что вам нужно

```
function check_multiplicity($n) {
  $m = $n % 3;
  if ($m !== 0)
    return $m;
}
```

Comment: мб просто `!$m` ? или по крайней мере `!=` достаточно.

Comment: в смысле я догадываюсь, что такая форма записи для понятности ТС, но можно сократить и написать комментарий в данном месте с более простой формой. чтобы ТС дополнительно чему то научился

Comment: @teran сравнение с нулем для новичка читабельнее. Строгое сравнение - производительнее

Comment: хм, что то я подумал, что наоборот строгое медленнее :)

Comment: @teram Нет же преобразования типов. Просто идет проверка типа и значения

Comment: @teran https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401478/why-is-faster-than-in-php

Comment: эт очевидно, да. Тупанул сперва и подумал что он сначала проверяет равенство, а потом дополнительно тип :D

Comment: Спасибо за ответы и помощь в столь простом вопросе , я сам аж ахнул.....XD|